# Foundation dropdown stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have a Foundation 5 dropdown on my page, which works fine. However when I submit a form in the dropdown area a new element is added to the top of the page so all the elements are moved down.
After that, all my dropdowns stop to work. (If I skip the adding of the element to the DOM, everything is working fine)

My dropdown:

```html
<div id="file-tab">
    <i data-dropdown="shareForm16" aria-controls="shareForm16" aria-expanded="false" class="iconTrigger"></i>
    <form data-dropdown-content class="share-form f-dropdown content" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" action="" id="shareForm16">
    ...         
    </form>
</div>
```

I thought I need to rebind the foundation event listeners, but it doesn't work. Maybe I am just doing it wrong.

```js
$('#file-tab').on("submit", 'form.share-form',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var groupName = $(form.target).find('input[type="text"]').val();
     var id = $(e.target).parent().children('input[type="hidden"]').val();
     if (groupName) {
           $(e.target).trigger('click');
           window.currentFTT.share(id ,groupName); // adds the element to the DOM
           // my attempt to rebind:
           $('#'+e.target.id).foundation({bindings: 'events'}); 
           $('i[aria-controls="'+e.target.id+'"]').foundation({bindings: 'events'}); 
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `foundation` for individual elements, make a general call to `foundation`, passing 'reflow' as a parameter:

`$(document).foundation('reflow');`

E.g:

```
$('#file-tab').on("submit", 'form.share-form',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var groupName = $(form.target).find('input[type="text"]').val();
     var id = $(e.target).parent().children('input[type="hidden"]').val();
     if (groupName) {
           $(e.target).trigger('click');
           window.currentFTT.share(id ,groupName); // adds the element to the DOM
           // my attempt to rebind:
           $(document).foundation('reflow');
     }
});
```